# How to switch the secondary display back to the mirror mode after start an Activity

Tags: android, multiple-monitors, mirror, android-displaymanager

I configured a secondary display for my android device. By default, the secondary display will mirror the content of the main diaplsy.

Then I use `DisplayManager.getDisplays(DisplayManager.DISPLAY_CATEGORY_PRESENTATION)`  to get secondary `displayId` and use `ActivityOptions` to start an `Activity` on secondary display, then it changes from mirror mode to show my `Activity` page.

Now I have a need to switch secondary display back to mirror mode **without finish `Activity`**, but I can't find any `API` to switch back to mirror mode.
So is there any way to flexibly switch the display mode of the secondary display?

My start `Activity` on secondary display code like this:

```
        val displays = displayManager.getDisplays(DisplayManager.DISPLAY_CATEGORY_PRESENTATION)
        val secondaryDisplay = displays.firstOrNull()
        if (secondaryDisplay != null) {
            val displayId = secondaryDisplay.displayId
            val context = activity.createDisplayContext(secondaryDisplay)
            val intent = Intent(context, activityClazz)
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

            if (isActivityStartAllowedOnDisplay(context, displayId, intent)) {
                val ops = ActivityOptions.makeBasic().apply { launchDisplayId = displayId }
                context.startActivity(intent, ops.toBundle())
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Cannot start activity to secondary display: $displayId")
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid finishing the activity?

Comment: you can assume there is a button on main display to switch secondary display between mirror mode and activity mode, so the opend activity can't finish

Comment: My guess is that you are better off using `Presentation`, as you get more control that way. The `ActivityOptions` approach is simpler to use but is designed for simple scenarios.